# Which is the best way to share objects with Marionette and Requirejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm starting to use Backbone.Marionette and I'm really excited about it.

I'm now trying to work with regions, and what I don't really know how to share the RegionManager. I've done this as you can see:

```
require(['backbone.marionette', 'cards-container', 'main-view'], function(Marionette, CardsContainer, MainView) {
   new MainView();
   window.app.RegionManager = new Marionette.RegionManager;
       window.app.RegionManager.addRegions({
         mainContainer: '.container',
         menu: '#menu',
         categoryBar: '.category-bar'
  })

});
```

Which I really think is not the best way to go.

I've been thinking to write this module as an amd one, and return the region manager or other things that I'd use on other modules:

```
 return {
    regionManager: rm
 }
```

Would be this better? If the answer is yes. Would this module be executed everytime I require it or require will just pick the region manager.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

RegionManager is accessible from anywhere, when there is usage of the Marionette module. So you don't have to create new RegionManager explicitly.

If i use this:

```
var MyApp = new Marionette.Application();

MyApp.addRegions({
  mainContainer: '.container',
  menu: '#menu',
  categoryBar: '.category-bar'
});
```

Then I can approach region just like this:

```
MyApp.mainContainer.show(new ShowView());
```

And can do it from any module, that has defined or that requires Marionette reference.

[Using marionette with requirejs](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Using-marionette-with-requirejs)

I would also recommend a book

> Structuring Backbone With Requirejs And Marionette by David Sulc.